# How to properly pass PHP object as parameter into called javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass my PHP array (Object) into my javascript function by doing this:

```
<td>
    <a href="#do=View?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="manageFormView(1, <?php echo json_encode($test) ;?>)"><i class="fas fa-eye cyan-text"></i></a>  
    <a href="#do=Edit?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt blue-grey-text"></i></a>
    <a href="#do=Delete?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash red-text"></i></a>
</td>
```

my concern is that whenever my `manageFormView` function is executed, it gives me this log:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

and the source is:

```
<a href="#do=View?id=1" onClick="manageFormView(1, {"id":"1","name":"Sample Departmentsss","code":"SDT"})"><i class="fas fa-eye cyan-text"></i></a>
```

**What syntax is missing?**

**EDIT**

```
function manageFormView(flag,row){
    document.getElementById("form3").value = row;
    console.log("flag and row "+flag+" "+row);
};
```

Comment: The value of your onclick attribute is just `manageFormView(1, {` - because after that comes the next `"`, which _ends_ the attribute value, since that is also the _starting_ delimiter you chose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the generated source. Identify the error:

```
onClick="manageFormView(1, {"
        1                   2
```

1. The quote that starts the attribute value
2. The quote that finishes the attribute value

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to make data safe for inserting into an attribute value in HTML.

---

Generating JS to insert into HTML which is inserted into PHP makes things relatively hard to manage.

I recommend inserting the data into [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and using JavaScript to bind a [delegated event handler](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) instead of using `onclick` attributes.

Comment: Sir is my usage of ```htmlspecialchars``` correct? This is how is insert on my code: ```<a href="#do=View?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="manageFormView('1', <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($test)) ;?>)"><i class="fas fa-eye cyan-text"></i></a>``` but it gives me: ```[object Object]```

Comment: @AnirudhLou — Yes. You are now passing the object to the function successfully. The function is just trying to treat the object as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your extra info sir. Indeed it makes it easier.

Comment: Sir is ```data-*``` also gets the values of table ```td```?